# Alignment buttons in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, alignment

I'm developing a Java application using NetBeans, but i can't find the button which allows me to align components.

In Visual Studio I can find this feature in the toolbar :

[image]

I googled about it, but I couldn't find anything.

where can I add these alignment buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the layout you're using, but you should be able to (for some of them), right click the panel and selecting customise layout